# How to 'pivot' a dataframe's values into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-science

I'm trying to transform a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'c1': ['x','y','z'],
'c2': [[1,2,3],[1,3],[2,4]]})
```

which looks like

```
    c1  c2
0   x   [1, 2, 3]
1   y   [1, 3]
2   z   [2, 4]
```

into

```
p = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': ['x','y','z'],
    1: [1,1,0],
    2: [1,0,1],
    3: [1,1,0],
    4: [0,0,1]
})
```

which looks like

```
    c1  1   2   3   4
0   x   1   1   1   0
1   y   1   0   1   0
2   z   0   1   0   1
```

the value 1's and 0's are supposed to be true and false. I'm still learning pivots. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['c2']),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)

df = df.drop('c2', 1).join(df1)
print (df)

  c1  1  2  3  4
0  x  1  1  1  0
1  y  1  0  1  0
2  z  0  1  0  1
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = df['c2'].apply(lambda x: '|'.join([str(y) for y in x])).str.get_dummies()

df = df.drop('c2', 1).join(df1)
print (df)
  c1  1  2  3  4
0  x  1  1  1  0
1  y  1  0  1  0
2  z  0  1  0  1
```

EDIT:

Thanks, [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48166900/how-to-pivot-a-dataframes-values-into-columns/48166981?noredirect=1#comment83314192_48166981) for nice suggestion:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('c2')),
                          columns‌​=mlb.classes_, 
                          index=df.index))
```

Comment: yeah, i think MultiLabelBinarizer is the most idiomatic approach in this case. We could do it in one line: `df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('c2')),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index))`

Comment: @MaxU - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
In [235]: df.join(pd.DataFrame([{x: 1 for x in r} for r in df.c2]).fillna(0))
Out[235]:
  c1         c2    1    2    3    4
0  x  [1, 2, 3]  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
1  y     [1, 3]  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  z     [2, 4]  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
```

Details

```
In [236]: pd.DataFrame([{x: 1 for x in r} for r in df.c2]).fillna(0)
Out[236]:
     1    2    3    4
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
```